# Doctrine Query builder error when using joins

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

In a photocontest have a **vote** entity that has the "imageId" field.

I would like to get a query containing the id of the vote and the fileName of the image which Id the vote carries. 
The entity looks like this:

```
class Vote
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="image_id")
     * @var integer $imageId
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Image")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $imageId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="date")
     */
    protected $date;
```

And the image it is linking to like this:

```
class Image {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, name="file_name")
     * @var string $fileName
     */
    protected $fileName;
```

Now I was trying to get the results out by using this query builder:

```
$votes = $qb -> select("v.id, i.fileName, v.date")
    ->from("AppBundle:Vote", "v")
    ->join("AppBundle:Image", "i")
    ->orderBy("v.id", "DESC")
    ->getQuery();
```

Using it in this configuration gives me an error saying:

> Expected Literal, got 'BY'

But after removing the orderBy I get this result

> Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got end of string.

I am aware that the error links to the fact that I didn't use the `WITH` param inside the join, but would like this to work 100% good and having it go fully through docrine relationships.

Whay could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: ->join('v.imageId', 'i')

Comment: @LBA `Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\Vote has no association named imageId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because in your entity, your imageId field is defined twice in doctrine :

```
@ORM\Column(type="integer", name="image_id")
```

and

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id")
```

You have to remove the first one ***(@ORM\Column)*** since its a join relation.

Plus, you have to defined it this way :

```
/**
 * @var Image
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Image")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id")
 */
protected $image;
```

You don't need more than that.

And in your VoteRepo :

```
$qb = $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('v')
    ->select('v.id, i.fileName, v.date')
    ->join('v.image', 'i')
    ->orderBy('v.id', 'DESC');
```

Comment: This seems working. What is now the best way to manually add element to database in mysql for testing? Since I had to remove my data

Comment: You can use fixtures for that : [http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html)